# Convert image to string (base64) in metro/windows 8 .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to convert an picture (that is stored in an object of type Image) to a string for storage (and later for conversion back into an Image object for display) in a metro app

I have found lots of answers for converting an image to a base64 string in .NET 4.0 etc but in 4.5 the System.Windows.Bitmap namespace isn't there (the Image class is in Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging) and the method that was in that namespace that made it possible in 4.0 "Save()" doesn't seem to be in 4.5...unless I just can't find it.

Theres an example of doing this [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/011c2c24-ffc5-4be5-883b-2430267b33c8/) but like I said it doesn't work in a metro app/.NET 4.5

any ideas?

more details:
the method that will do this will convert an instance field that contains an image object (ive used its source property, is this correct?) and needs to store the resultant string from the conversion in an instance string field. this whole object can then be serialized, ignoring the Image field, with the hope of deserializing later and restoring the string to the Image field for display. so far ive tried to use a DataContractSerializer to serialize string from the image, but it doesn't seem to like it. Once I get a string from the image I would be able to serialize that, but its not something I've ever done before.

Also, it seems that the only .net 4.5 documentation that is definitely correct is the pages here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/

pages at the "normal looking" msdn site for .net 4.5 don't seem to always work in metro apps? (just a theory?)

**[solved]**

I finally got it! for anyone else that ever has to do this the answer is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/38c6cb85-7454-424f-ae94-32782c036567/

I did this

```
var reader = new DataReader(myMemoryStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
var bytes  = new byte[myMemoryStream.Size];
await reader.LoadAsync((uint)myMemoryStream.Size);
reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
```

after this sequence, the byte array `bytes` will have the data from the stream in it, from there I set a string to the value of

```
Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: You could probably use the WriteableBitmapExtensions to convert the image to a byte array which you can then convert to a base64 encoded string: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ They have Windows 8 metro support, but I haven't worked with it in Metro so I won't post this as answer.

Comment: And that's it. This is trick, i'll mark this question as fav because certainly I will need this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it! for anyone else that ever has to do this the answer is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/38c6cb85-7454-424f-ae94-32782c036567/

I did this

```
var reader = new DataReader(myMemoryStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
var bytes  = new byte[myMemoryStream.Size];
await reader.LoadAsync((uint)myMemoryStream.Size);
reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
```

after this sequence, the byte array bytes will have the data from the stream in it, from there I set a string to the value of

```
Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: its just converting image to base64 but how to convert base64string to BitmapImage or WritebleBitmapImage ?

Comment: To convert backwards convert the string to bytes, write the bytes to a memory stream and set the source of a BitmapImage to the stream

Comment: BitmapImage take source RandomAccessMemory giving error when converting memoryStream object to RandomAccess ms.AsRandomAccess()

Comment: but I had done this with InMemoryRandomAccessStream and DataWriter class. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that's how I did it:
var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
            var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
            dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
            dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            ims.Seek(0);
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            img.SetSource(ims);
            return img;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of this because I do not have the .net 4.5 installed here, but I think this could work:

You could use the BitmapSource.CopyPixels() method to extract the pixels of the image:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616043(v=vs.110).aspx

Then use Convert.ToBase64String() to do the convertion.

Also, here are some useful imaging HOW-TOs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750864(v=vs.110)

Comment: You should link to the 4.5 version instead of the 4.0 version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616043(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks! I tried this and I find that despite what the documentation says VS wont accept the Media.Imaging namespace where the CopyPixels is defined, and Intellisense doesn't show CopyPixels for BitmapImage or BitmapSource -_- Would this by any chance work if I imported the PresentationCore.dll where this method is defined? I've never done that sort of thing before so I have no idea if it could work

Comment: I believe ive made a little progress, ive been able to get the image data into a stream (IRandomAccessStream)
Ive then done byte[] array = (stream as MemoryStream).ToArray();
however this throws a NullReferenceException? After that I believe I could do
string base64string = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
but the exception is currently preventing this step

Answer (score 0):

Try [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx).  [Example of how to create a BitmapEncoder here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465076.aspx#create_an_encoder_object_for_a_new_or_existing_image).  The appropriate namespace is `Windows.Graphics.Imaging`.

`BitmapEncoder` gets you an encoder.  You can then use `GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat, BitmapAlphaMode, BitmapTransform, ExifOrientationMode, ColorManagementMode)` to get your pixel data.  Following that you can use any generic C# base64 encoder.

(Examples are Javascript but should work for C# as well since the classes exist in C#)

Comment: thanks! I have tried this and while it might have worked, I cant work out how to use the encoder classes! I have been trying not to reference an actual file in the code, as a file of the image may not always be the source of the image (the camera may be used to take it there and then, and that value is stored in the image object instead) so I haven't made things any easier. I may come back to it again if I cant find another method.

Comment: You can create a bitmapencoder from a stream.  You should be able to combine that with @Feng Yuan's answer to have a working `BitmapEncoder`.

Comment: I see, honestly its still a little confusing, but I think I'm closer to the answer. I have now got the image in an IRandomAccessStream, which was set from the file being picked. How can I now get the contents of this stream into the form I want?

Comment: The `BitmapEncoder` class has a constructor `CreateAsync(Guid, IRandomAccessStream)` make that and then use the `GetPixelDataAsync` method to retrieve the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the encoded format of image (say JPEG) format, decoded back to byte[], create a MemoryStream, then Metro BitmapImage can be created from the stream.